# Rails: Can I create and save an object instance within a class method on a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, class, model, instance

Is it possible and kosher to use a class method on a model to create a new instance of the same model?

The scenario is that I want to interact with an external API, create an instance on the other service, and then once completed successfully store that new object reference in a local model.

So for example I want to call something like this from the controller:

```
MyModel.interact_with_api_function([variables required])
```

And have a class method like this on the model:

```
def interact_with_api([variables required])
  interacts with api, generates object over there, returns result
  This.new(identifier: result, ...).save!
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Is it possible and kosher to use a class method on a model to create a new instance of the same model?**

Yes, you can do that. In fact, when you do something like `MyModel.first`, that's exactly what's happening. `first` is a class method, which fetches a row from the database, creates a new instance of your model, and then populates it with the data fetched from that database call.

**The scenario is that I want to interact with an external API, create an instance on the other service, and then once completed successfully store that new object reference in a local model.**

If you think of the SQL call to the database as similar to a call to an external API (ie, the database is an external service, like your API), then the situation in the `first` method is not that unlike what you're doing.

Likewise, the `MyModel.create` method is a class method, built into Rails, that both creates a new instance of that model, and then saves it to the database - again, not unlike what you're doing.

So, I'd say it's fine.